# Add shader for SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, shader, skspritenode

I want to add drop shadow effect for a `SKShapeNode`. I found a `Emboss` shader [here](https://github.com/twostraws/ShaderKit/blob/master/Shaders/SHKEmbossColor.fsh).

Here is my code:

```
let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: w, height: h),cornerRadius: w / 4.0)
node.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: frame.size.height + h / 2)
node.fillColor = color
node.strokeColor = .clear
node.fillShader = createColorEmboss()
let v = simd_make_float2(Float(w),Float(h))
node.setValue(SKAttributeValue(vectorFloat2: v), forAttribute: "a_size")

func createColorEmboss() -> SKShader {
    let source = "void main() {" +
        "vec4 current_color = SKDefaultShading();" +
        "if (current_color.a > 0.0) {" +
            "vec2 pixel_size = 1.0 / a_size;" +
            "vec4 new_color = current_color;" +
            "new_color += texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord + pixel_size) * u_strength;" +
            "new_color -= texture2D(u_texture, v_tex_coord - pixel_size) * u_strength;" +
            "gl_FragColor = vec4(new_color.rgb, 1) * current_color.a * v_color_mix.a;" +
        "} else {" +
            "gl_FragColor = current_color;" +
        "}" +
    "}"
    let shader = SKShader(source: source, uniforms: [SKUniform(name: "u_strength", float: 1)])
    shader.attributes = [SKAttribute(name: "a_size", type: .vectorFloat2)]
    return shader  
  }
```

But nothing happened. Any idea?

Comment: I haven't tried running your code, but from just looking at it I notice that you haven't set the shader attribute's value.  It appears that it's supposed to be set to the node's size.  So at a minimum you'd need something along the lines of `node.setValue(SKAttributeValue(vectorFloat2: ...), forAttribute: "a_size")`

Comment: Still doesn't work after I add this.

Comment: Looking again, you haven't set fillTexture either.  Probably u_texture in the shader is nothing.  It might be easier to get a feel for things if you're just getting started with shaders by trying an SKSpriteNode made from a texture.  Shader debugging can be an exercise in pulling your hair out, and I don't have the experience using them with SKShapeNodes to tell you exactly what you're missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some big differences between a textured **(*)** `SKShapeNode` and `SKSpriteNode` here:

- If the `SKSpriteNode` has a texture and a custom shader (`shader` property), then the shader will have access to the original texture via the `u_texture` uniform, and it will be able use it for rendering the node, i.e. by applying various effects to it like emboss, blur, etc.
- `SKShapeNode` *may* have a `fillTexture` and a `fillShader`, but the way they work is different:

  - `fillTexture` is a rectangular texture that's converted to grayscale and used to set the luminosity of `fillColor` in the areas of the shape node which are filled.
  - `fillShader` can only see `fillTexture` as this rectangular image before it gets used for the final render, with no way to modify, or even see, which areas of the rectangle will be visible (part of the fill), and how the final render will look.
  - If there is no explicit `fillTexture` set, the `u_texture` uniform seems to pretend that it's an endless expanse of whiteness: whatever coordinate you ask about, it will return the color white, even if you go out of its bounds.

---

**(*)** You can also create a `SKSpriteNode` with just a color; its behavior will be a weird mix of `SKShapeNode` and a textured `SKSpriteNode`, and it's not helpful for our discussion, so I'll be ignoring this kind.

---

What you can do is to rasterize your `SKShapeNode` into a texture, and create an `SKSpriteNode` from it. It's actually very simple:

```
let node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: w, height: h),cornerRadius: w / 4.0)
node.fillColor = color
node.strokeColor = .clear

let theTexture = view.texture(from:node)
let spriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture:theTexture)

spriteNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: frame.size.height + h / 2)
spriteNode.shader = createColorEmboss()
let v = simd_make_float2(Float(w),Float(h))
spriteNode.setValue(SKAttributeValue(vectorFloat2: v), forAttribute: "a_size")
```

As you can see, you don't even have to add the node to the scene; the view will render it into a texture, with a clear background. You can also use `view.texture(from:crop:)` to specify a larger crop that can accommodate a drop shadow if it extends beyond the original shape.

I must warn you, however, that this particular shader you are trying to use may not be what you need for a drop shadow…